# Should I request for higher raise of salary after probation?

Tags: salary, raise, probation

During the interview session I request for the lowest offered salary range (*e.g. 2,300 with range of 2,300 ~ 2,500*). After some times in probation along with my colleagues which are also under probation period, they told me that most of them choose the highest one within the offered salary range.
I admit that I did not consider much on *expectation salary strategy* since I am fresh graduated and I have to be humble for my first job. I really try hard to show that I'm capable to complete the assigned tasks and the will to learn things. 
I know that for sure there will be a fixed amount of raise in salary but am I qualified to request for extra of raise after probation period or I'm just sound too greedy in this case? Should I accept what I requested in the beginning of the interview session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would wait until an annual appraisal where you can showcase your work throughout the year and it will be a good opportunity to demonstrate why you feel the raise is needed.